# Possible to update Azure Web App Setting with LinqPad?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, linqpad, application-settings

I wondering if it's possible to update Azure Web App Configuration settings using the LinqPad application?  For reference of where in the web app that needs to be updated, please see image below.

[image]

I know it's possible to update the Networking Settings using LinqPad (a colleague created the script).  I have the login credentials (Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication.ApplicationTokenProvider) and subscription id (Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.WebSiteManagementClient).  Yet, when try to use WebApps (from the 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites' assembly/Namespace), I'm not sure what I'm suppose to use or if it's even possible to do this.

Comment: Hi, I'm here want to check if the issue can be solved as per answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can create a Service Principle(use [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) or [azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal)) first for authentication, then install this package [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/).

Then use the code below to Add or Update Application Settings in azure portal:

```
public static void UpdateSetting(string key, string value)
{
    string tenantId = "xx";
    string clientSecret = "xx";
    string clientId = "xxx";
    string subscriptionId = "xx";

    //resource group name
    string rg_name = "xx";

    //azure web app name
    string app_name = "xxx";

    var azureCredentials = new AzureCredentials(new
      ServicePrincipalLoginInformation
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        ClientSecret = clientSecret
    }, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);


    var myazure = Azure
        .Configure()
        .Authenticate(azureCredentials)
        .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

    var webapp = myazure.WebApps.GetByResourceGroup(rg_name, app_name);
    webapp.Update()
        .WithAppSetting(key, value)
        .Apply();                                                
}
```